# How to allow users to add photos to an app that could be viewed by others using Firebase

Tags: ios, swift, database, firebase

If I wanted to make an app that allows users to add their own photos to a UICollectionview what method would I use? Also, how could that be added to Firebase's real-time database?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to give your users access to the camera and photo library.

You wouldn’t use the Firebase real-time database, you could use the Firebase Storage module, but I would use a product like Cloudinary, which allows you to do nice things like centring, resizing, facial detection etc.

Comment: Mark Sir, you are sincerely the MVP! I may have a few more questions later. Hopefully you don't mind me asking. I'll be sure to pay forward. Thank you.

Comment: If I wanted to add geolocation to the images so that the location can be queried via distance buffer, would I need to use GeoFire or a similar solution?

Comment: If you are using Firebase the Next i would use GeoFire, it’s a good solution, and easy to implement